# How to send Only Selected value to another screen in KivyMD?

Tags: python, screen, kivymd

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ynu.jpg) KivyMD Programmers, im new in KivyMD....

on_start() list items are sucessfully showing and on_press sending a selected value too passValue() function....

but here now i wants open new Screen under passValue() function...and pass variable value's to new Screen....

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

#Builder String
helper_string = '''
ScreenManager:
    Hello:
    Bye:
<Hello>:
    name: 'hello'
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: list
            
<Bye>:
    name: 'bye'
    MDLabel:        
        text:'Good Bye'
    MDLabel:
        id:'aaa'
        text:""

'''
class Hello(Screen):
    pass
class Bye(Screen):
    pass
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Hello(name = 'hello'))
sm.add_widget(Bye(name = 'bye'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()

        self.help_str = Builder.load_string(helper_string)

        screen.add_widget(self.help_str)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(50):        
            item = OneLineListItem(text='Item ' + str(i),            
            on_release=lambda x, value_for_pass={i}: self.passValue(value_for_pass)
            )                                    
            self.help_str.get_screen('hello').ids.list.add_widget(item)
        

    def passValue(self, *args): 
        args_str = ','.join(map(str,args))
        print(args_str)        
        self.help_str.get_screen('bye').manager.current = 'bye' #how to pass/send args_str's value to bye screen???

DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly where in your screen `Bye` you want to pass a variable. Here, you can access any element from any screen via `root`. Also you can create any specific one according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for reply ApuCoder, i want attached output https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CQV6bVNFUS1H6T74HALSrres4fhhbBaM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should describe/post that as text rather than an image whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since It's not clear exactly where in your screen `Bye` you want some variable to be passed, let's suppose you want to pass a list's `text` to the `MDLabel` having `text` 'Good Bye' of the screen `Bye` by method `passValue`.

You may achieve this as follows:

First in the `kvlang` of screen `Bye` assign an `id` say, `target` to the `MDLabel`,

```py
<Bye>:
    name: 'bye'
    MDLabel:
        id: target
        text:'Good Bye'
```

Then in your method `passValue`,

```py
    def passValue(self, *args): 
        args_str = ','.join(map(str,args))
        print(args_str)
        bye_screen = self.help_str.get_screen('bye')
        bye_screen.manager.current = 'bye'
        bye_screen.ids.target.text = args_str
```

As a side note you perhaps don't need (as you already defined that in `kvlang`) the following:

```py
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Hello(name = 'hello'))
sm.add_widget(Bye(name = 'bye'))
```

Comment: Oh Really! Very Thankful to you ApuCoder... It is working now....